# jQuery .each() some changes to html not made

Tags: jquery, html

On window load I am trying to check if my image has already been saved and if so change the HTML so that the link to save it is disabled. This code kind of works without the `.each()` with but only finds the first tag and changes all other similar tags based on that. Of course I want the do each tag separately. From looking at the post transactions in firebug, each ajax call processes properly and is sent the correct `href` value but the html updates don't seem to take. The if statement isn't failing because the alert message comes on when it should. Any idea why the `$(this)` works for retrieving the item value but doesn't work when setting the html changes?

```
window.onload =  function() {
    $(".img a").each(function() {
        var item=$(this).attr( 'href' );
        var action="check";
        jqxhr = $.post("webservice.php", { action: action, color: item }, function(data) {
            var result=data.result;
            if (result=="saved") {
                $(this).html("<div style='line-height:4em '>Saved</div>");
                $(this).attr("href","saved");
                alert(result);
            }

        }, "json")
        .error(function() {         
            alert("error: unable to contact web service"); 
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle showing the code failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `this` inside the callback does not refer to the element you think.

You need to create a reference to that element before the ajax and use that.

```
window.onload =  function() {
    $(".img a").each(function() {
        var self   = $(this),
            item   = this.href,
            action = "check";
        jqxhr = $.post("webservice.php", { action: action, color: item }, function(data) {
            var result=data.result;
            if (result=="saved") {
                self.html("<div style='line-height:4em '>Saved</div>");
                self.attr("href","saved");
                alert(result);
            }

        }, "json")
        .error(function() {         
            alert("error: unable to contact web service"); 
        });
    });
}
```

---

Additionally it does seem like an overkill to run so many ajax call to check a similar thing.
It might be a better idea to refactor your code to make a single ajax call, but pass it a list of files to check and then handle the response which would refer to all those images (*one-by-one*)

Comment: Yes, this works thanks. I will looking to making this one call but it's pretty fast as it is.

Answer (score 1):

There's some rules in javascript closures.
sometimes in different closures `this` is a different reference.

Try

```
var that = $(this);
```

and use `that` for the item ref everywhere u need

Answer (score 1):

the caller of the success method is not the `<a>` element.

```
window.onload =  function() {
$(".img a").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var item=$(this).attr( 'href' );
    var action="check";
    jqxhr = $.post("webservice.php", { action: action, color: item }, function(data) {
        var result=data.result;
        if (result=="saved") {
            $this.html("<div style='line-height:4em '>Saved</div>");
            $this.attr("href","saved");
            alert(result);
        }

    }, "json")
    .error(function() {         
        alert("error: unable to contact web service"); 
    });
});
}
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
var item=$(this).attr( 'href' );
```

to:

```
var $item = $(this);
var item=$item.attr( 'href' );
```

Then change:

```
$(this).html("<div style='line-height:4em '>Saved</div>");
$(this).attr("href","saved");
```

To:

```
$item.html("<div style='line-height:4em '>Saved</div>");
$item.attr("href","saved");
```